# Add liquibase to PATH not recognized

Tags: path, environment-variables, classpath, liquibase

I downloaded the latest Liquibase .zip file from http://www.liquibase.org/download/index.html

Then, I added the path to my liquibase.bat file (C:\liquibase-3.5.3-bin) to my Environment Variables: User variable PATH and System Variable PATH.

However, the command liquibase is still not recognized in the commandline.  Am I missing something for liquibase?

Thanks.

Comment: did you fixed it?

Comment: @aurelius Yep I did. Thanks for asking.  I believe that restarting the computer did the trick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows)